# Making sure that item can only be bought by 1 person when 4000 people are trying to buy within a seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase

I run a marketplace iOS app and from time to time we have "competitions", where we have an especially sought after item for sale for a good price, that drops as a specific time. Sometimes thousands of people will try to buy this item within 1-2 seconds and I therefore need to make sure that only 1 person will get the item. The solution I have for it now feels kind of clumsy, so I was wondering how a good solution would look like when I use Firebase as my database.

The process is as such:

1. User finds the item on his iOS app and clicks "Purchase".
2. A request is sent to our API (build on RoR) that processes the purchase (usually takes 10-20 seconds for the purchase to go through).

Right now, I set the buyers ID temporarily as an attribute on the item, I wait a second and check whether the buyer ID is still the same on the item. It works, but it doesn't feel optimal.

Any suggestions on how I can make sure 2 people can't purchase the same item?

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/XVSHhINIk-0

Comment: Why doesn't it feel optimal? Why is it clumsy? Understanding what isn't working will help refine an answer. Firebase can handle this task but I think more info is needed since it's a slightly vacuous question. Have you tried anything in Firebase? How does its performance compare to what you are doing now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store in **/items/foo**

a record with the structure:

```
{id:<blah>, available: <timestamp>, (purchaser: null)}
```

let buyers write their user name to to buy:

```
/item/foo/purchaser
```

You want 3 things to happen.

1. Block someone writing before the servers timestamp of available
2. only allow 1 person to do the operation. Once the /item/foo/purchaser is set, you don't want it modifiable (i.e. write once)
3. only allow the authenticated user id to be used in the purchaser field

To enforce this logic you use security rules, on the subpath of "/items/$itemid/purchaser"

```
".write": "now > data.parent().child('available').val()" +// 1.
          "&& data.val() == null" +                       // 2.
          "&& newData.val() == auth.id"                   // 3.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up doing something very similar to this.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid something like this in your rails app, the keywords `mutex` and `race condition` should probably help you to find a bunch of appropriate gems.

I personally like to use redis for this kind of task, because in redis, transactions are atomic by default (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)).

So maybe this gem could suit your needs (untested): https://github.com/kenn/redis-mutex.

For the theory, refer to this articles:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Answer (score 2):

My guess is tht you should use locks. 
On a request coming in, check if you can acquire a lock. If yes, the the user is the first one. Then, the next requests won't be able to acquire the lock. This means the product as already been purchased.

Take a look at this redis doc part : http://redis.io/topics/distlock

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not using Redis though. Is this concept a lock a programming pattern you can apply to other things?

Answer (score 2):

At the application(RoR) level, you can set a flag(eg: `lock_foo=true`) that is shared across the cluster(can be in your cache store).

If this value is true, don't allow any other users to access the product/make the purchase.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely implement this with Firebase. As dvxam and Anshul Mengi mentioned, a lock system is the good way to go:

You could have on the document a property called lock:

```
{
    "lock": {
        "userId": "myUserId",
        "expiresAt": "myTimestamp"
    }
}
```

When a user clicks on the purchase button, you can use a Firebase [transaction](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html) to make sure only one user can get the lock and that the first one gets it.
When another user clicks the purchase button, if a non-expired lock is present with a different userId, you can deny the purchase.
When the user completes the purchase you can then use another transaction to check if it is the same userId and if the lock is not expired.

Transactions are absolutely necessary here, and they are not available on the Firebase REST api (hence no more in the ruby wrapper), so you would need to run this code client-side using the iOS SDK, or to spin a nodeJS server for this task.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Seems like a good pattern. Would I be possible to do without transactions? Could I set a security rule on the user-id, so only the first ID would be able to be written there and then check after I've tried to write if it's the users ID?

Comment: You can definitely express that the node can be created and not updated, with something like: `"lock": {".write": "!data.exists()"}` but I don't think this gives you any guarantees in case of concurrent requests. Two concurrent requests could pass the rule simultaneously, in which case both would receive a success response, but one would *win* the race - i think. Transactions are meant to give you the opportunity to react to concurrent requests. I'd rather have a response from a team member on this, but i really think that you would need a transaction in such a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

How about this for different:

- When user clicks purchase, immediately create a purchase request record that contains product, user and timestamp, and then poll every few seconds to see if the purchase was successful
- Run a background job that searches for un-purchased products that have at least one purchase request against them, and marks the product as purchased (selecting one purchase request / user as the "winner")

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if there's a specific pattern I can apply in this case or how this is "normally" solved?

I can't speak to Firebase, but I can definitely speak to how this is "normally" solved in Rails and relational databases.

Before jumping in to code, note that it seems like you need [linearizability](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/05/11/please-stop-calling-databases-cp-or-ap.html#linearizability), one of the hardest things to ask of a database, and some databases [can't guarantee it even when they say they do](https://aphyr.com/posts/322-jepsen-mongodb-stale-reads). You might be able to hack around needing linearizability if all you need to know is whether it's been purchased or not, but I wouldn't take that hack lightly. Consistency in distributed systems is a really complex and edge-case-ridden topic, especially while under load (which it sounds like you'll be).

In Rails+RDB (postgres, mysql, sqlite) an atomic, linearized quantity update looks roughly like this (with some rails validation niceities thrown in):

```
class Product
  validates :quantity, numericality: {greater_than: 0}, on: :purchase

  def purchase
    with_lock do # simultaneously aquires a lock and reloads the model
      return false if !valid?(:purchase) # immediately release the lock if not valid
      update_attribute(:quantity, quantity - 1) # saves without validation; YYMV
    end
  end
end
```

This general pattern of "lock+reload -> check -> update" is the gold standard for reliability, but it's "heavy." The first object to acquire the lock will win, but while it's doing its thing, all the other processes asking for a lock will be in queue. Somewhere there's a timeout and max connection pool defined, so if say 4000 locks are asked for within 1 second but it takes 10 seconds to determine success, you'll need 4000 connections and, even worse, the last lock asked for will be waiting for over 11 hours! That will make managing the connection pools and setting reasonable timeouts challenging.

The benefits, though, are that it will "just work" - if the first purchase fails, the next purchase will acquire a lock, and so on, until someone wins. Then, it will return helpful ActiveModel errors to everyone else in the queue. Additionally, it's simple enough code-wise that you know as long as your database provides linearizability, you're in the clear.

To mitigate the 11-hours issue hopefully you can very quickly deny everyone with outstanding locks to flush the queue.

I don't know exactly what you're doing while you try to make a purchase, but if it was just a credit card validation and a data update, I'd highly recommend the approach I've outlined with a database known to be linearizably consistent. Otherwise, you're going to need to consult a true distributed systems expert or run your users under the bus figuring this out.